# Make div with overflow grow and shrink until 100% of parent

Tags: css, vuetify.js

I have this data table that contains certain elements. I want it to shrink or grow based on the amount of data, but stop growing when the height reaches 100% of the parent, and then it should show a scroll overflow.

I have a working version [here](https://codepen.io/theonlyerror/pen/QWLEVGe). Which basically uses the hacky rules below to kinda make it work.

```
.content {
  height: 10px !important;
}  
.table-container {
  height: 100% !important;
}
.table-container /deep/ .v-data-table {
  height: calc(100% - 64px) !important;
}
.table-container /deep/ .v-data-table__wrapper {
  height: 100% !important;
}
```

I want it to look like [this](https://codepen.io/theonlyerror/pen/dybXqWd) when it contains just a few elements, but instead it looks like [this](https://codepen.io/theonlyerror/pen/gOYMdgB).

Make div with overflow grow and shrink until 100% of parent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if i understand you correctly.

```
.layout {
  box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.15);
}
.table-container {
    height: auto;
  max-height:100%;
  overflow:auto;
  }
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/Cleee/pen/OJLRYrM)

But if you want the content to define the height of an Container, just set the height to auto as default. To define the point when the scrollbar shall appear use max-height. And overflow:auto; for the scrollbar.

Comment: It should look like the first codepen for many elements, and like the second codepen for a few items. But currently, it looks like the third codepen for few items. That is the problem (which this does not solve unfortunately).

Comment: Ok now my Pen got the same behaviour like your first for many items and like your second pen for a few. If i got the right order :D Seems like you just had to add a max-height to the right container.
`.table-container /deep/ .v-data-table__wrapper {
   max-height: calc(100vh - 100px);
 } `
https://codepen.io/Cleee/pen/OJLRYrM

Answer (score 0):

you can use a combination of max-height and overflow like this

```
html, body {
  overflow: hidden !important;
}

.content {
  height: 10px !important;
}  
.table-container {
  max-height: 100vh;
}
.layout.table-container{
  overflow:auto;
}
```

Comment: Did you try it in the codepens I provided? That does not seem to work. I want it to look like the first codepen for many elements, and the second for a few elements.

Comment: try now, before there was a double scroll bar in first one but it was working in 2nd one. Now it is working as expected in both

Comment: Still isn't the same unfortunately, the wrong elements overflow. (The headers should still show). And the margin at the bottom is also no longer there.